# How can i send the values to the next page without the showing the values in the address bar

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here am sending a value month from a page to a php file named printall.php on clicking an image print.png. I get that value in printall.php by using GET method. I find the value of of month  displaying in the address bar of the window which opens printall.php on Clicking print.png.

I want to hide or encode the value which displays in the address bar. Is that anyone to help me out with this little doubt ?

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('printall.php?id=<?php echo $month;?>');"><img src="print.png" width="25px" height="22px" style="border:0;" ></a>
```

Comment: are you using cookies or sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $month the value of the current month, or is it based on user input? If it is the value of the current month, don't bother sending it to your PHP script, just use PHP's native datetime functions:

```
echo date('m'); // would echo 08 since current month is August
```

If $month is somehow based on user input, either of the other 2 answers would work, using AJAX or by submitting a form.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a form in the page that uses post and invisible fields. Then using javascript then set the month on the invisible field and submit it.

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but is there any other way to do it ? just curious to know. If there is no way other than using post. I will use that.

Comment: @John_mc Well, it's the most convenient way. You can do sex with ajax+sessions/whatever but it would be hunting squirrel with a howitzer if all you want is just to pass that variable once. :) However, if you rely on that variable being correct and may give unpredictable result if wrong value is given then you must use sessions and not rely on data received from browser.

Comment: Thanks for a clear explaination Salva...I will stick with POST...thanks alot once again...CHEERS!

Answer (score 0):

you can make POST submits with JavaScript; libraries like jQuery have nice Ajax utility functions.

Answer (score 0):

PHP $_POST Function

The built-in $_POST function is used to collect values from a form sent with method="post".

Information sent from a form with the POST method is invisible to others and has no limits on the amount of information to send.

Note: However, there is an 8 Mb max size for the POST method, by default (can be changed by setting the post_max_size in the php.ini file).

Ex.

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Url look like

```
http://www.w3schools.com/welcome.php
```

Source: w3schools